# PROBLEMA DE GRABACIÓN JITSI MEET - API YOUTUBE V3 - INTEGRACIÓN MOODLE

Tags: api, youtube, moodle

Un cordial saludo, instale Moodle en un hosting e hice la integración de Jitsi meet mediante un servidor público y la extensión que ofrece Moodle. Todo el proceso con éxito pero al intentar acceder a la grabación automática de las clases que ofrece no tuve éxito, ingresé todos los datos solicitados ID OAuth2 y Clave OAuth2, asimismo active las transmisiones en mi cuenta de Youtube y la API de Youtube V3. Al intentar habilitar la grabación  y transmisión en la consola del navegador me arroja este mensaje

```html
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Scheduled start time must be in the future and close enough to the current date that a broadcast could be reliably scheduled at that time.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Scheduled start time must be in the future and close enough to the current date that a broadcast could be reliably scheduled at that time.",
        "domain": "youtube.liveBroadcast",
        "reason": "invalidScheduledStartTime",
        "extendedHelp": "https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts#snippet.scheduledStartTime"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualización del problema, logré quitar el error 400 pero al parecer me ocasionó un error diferente en otro módulo. Modifique el archivo external.php que se encuentra en la ruta /public_html/mod/jitsi/classes

```html
        try {
            date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
            $broadcastsnippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_LiveBroadcastSnippet();
            //$testdate = time() + (45 * 60);
            $testdate = time();

            $broadcastsnippet->setTitle("Record ".date('Y-m-d\T H:i A', $testdate));
            $broadcastsnippet->setScheduledStartTime(date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', $testdate));

[...]
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero puedan ayudarme solucionar este problema, muchas gracias

Comment: El mensaje de error es bastante descriptivo: la fecha debe estar en el futuro pero no lejano

Comment: Claro que entiendo el mensaje, la pregunta es ¿Cómo lo soluciono?